# Is there a prover just for propositional logic

Tags: isabelle

I tried to implement LTL logic syntactically  using the axiomatization command, with the purpose of automatically finding proofs for theorems (motivation of proving program properties).

However the automatic provers such as (cvc4, z3, e, etc) all use quantifiers of some sort. For example using FOL one could prove F(p)-->G(p) which is obviously false.

My question is if there exists a prover, just like the ones mentioned, but that is made for propositional logic, i.e. only has access to MP and the propositional logic axioms.

I am rather new to isabelle so there might be an easier way of doing this im not seeing.

EDIT: I am looking for a hilbert style deduction prover and not a SAT as this would defeat the problem of implementing it axiomatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the `sat` method only uses propositional logic.

However, I would recommend not to use axiomatizations and just define the syntax of LTL using datatypes and the semantics using functions. Maybe you can reuse the formalization from https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/LTL.html

Without axiomatizations you are then free to use any method.

Comment: I am currently trying to avoid the semantic approach as you need to enconde states and valuation words into it, making it very hard for it to auto prove. 

My question is if there is a prover which can create Hilbert type deductions based on the axioms I provide. Sat can only give me the satisfability on a certain state, meaning id have to code the states in, so I feel like the axiomatization would provide an interesting ammount of simplicity

Comment: You can follow the semantics approach and still keep the state and predicates abstract. If a FOL prover could derive `F(p)-->G(p)` from your axioms, I guess your axioms are not correct. Otherwise, if your axioms are correct, I don't see why you cannot use something more powerful like sledgehammer, blast, or metis. Maybe you can share your axioms and some LTL properties that you want to prove?

Comment: The axioms are the following

(A0) G◦ ϕ, for every tautological formula ϕ

(A1) (G◦ ϕ) → ϕ
(A2) (X ¬ ϕ) ⇔ (¬ X ϕ)
(A3) X(ϕ → ψ) ⇒ (X ϕ → X ψ)
(A4) G◦(ϕ → ψ) ⇒ (G◦ ϕ → G◦ ψ)
(A5) G◦ ϕ → G◦ X ϕ
(A6) (ϕ ⇒ X ϕ) → (ϕ → G◦ ϕ)
(A7) ϕ U ψ ⇔ ψ ∨ (ϕ ∧ X(ϕ U ψ))
(A8) ϕ U ψ ⇒ F◦ ψ

and using isabelle you can prove F p equivalent G p

Can you share print screens on SO ? I can show it if its possible

Comment: This looks like `G` is a function of type `bool  => bool` in your axiomatization. However, in LTL there also is an implicit argument which is the trace on which the formula is evaluated. I think `G` should have a type like `(trace => bool) => trace => bool`. Of course that is a bit more tedious to write down ...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a SAT solver, such as [minisat](http://minisat.se/).

> However the automatic provers such as (cvc4, z3, e, etc) all use quantifiers of some sort. For example using FOL one could prove F(p)-->G(p) which is obviously false.

This is not correct. Any first-order theorem prover, like iProver, E, Vampire, will *not* prove `forall X. f(X) => g(x)`.

Comment: I think I explained myself wrong F and G are specific to LTL, F meaning eventualy p will happen and G always p.

My question is Sat solvers work based on satisfability, exactly what im trying to avoid on LTL and basing myself on Hilbert type deductions. I want to know if there is an automatic prover which can create hilbert like deductions based on the axioms i provide